# How to get links right in a singly linked list in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm supposed to implement a singly linked list using assembly(masm x86).

I've done the 'append' function, and the 'print' function so far, but I can't figure out where the problem is(the code compiles but doesn't do anything once I try to run it). I'm hoping that someone will point out the mistakes I made.

The 'append' function's parameters are `offset first` and `givenKey`

```
append proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]

    allocate:
        push len
        call malloc
        add esp, 4
        mov esi, [ebp+12]
        mov dword ptr [eax], esi
        mov dword ptr [eax+4], 0

    is_first:
        cmp dword ptr [ebx], 0
        je first?

    next:
        cmp dword ptr [ebx+4], 0
        je add_last
        mov ebx, [ebx+4]
        jmp next

    first?:
        mov dword ptr[first], esi
        jmp done

    add_last:
        mov [ebx+4], eax
        mov eax, dword ptr [eax]
        mov dword ptr [ebx+4], eax
        jmp done

    done:
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret 8   
append endp
```

These are my variables and the data structure:

```
Node struct
    key dd 0
    next dd 0
Node ends

first Node {0, 0}

len equ sizeof Node
format db "%d ", 0
```

And finally the 'print' function(which has no parameters):

```
print proc
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov ebx, offset first
    et:
    cmp dword ptr [ebx], 0
    je done
    push dword ptr [ebx]
    push offset format
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    mov ebx, [ebx+4]
    jmp et
done:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
print endp
```

If I try to append a single number and print the list it works as expected. For two numbers it only prints the first one and then crashes, and for three or more numbers it just crashes.
The `printf` and `malloc` functions are included from `msvcrt.lib`.

Comment: One issue appears to be that, for the very first element, you store the value directly in `first` - you don't store the newly allocated `eax` pointer. Aside: It seems odd that you pass in `offset first` as a parameter but then go on to access `first` directly.

Comment: I tried to keep the very first element in ```first``` as I couldn't give it the values given at ```[eax]```.

Comment: `first` should not be a node but rather a pointer to a node, which you then write the initial value of `eax` to (after `malloc`).